# How to install keras-rl in Anaconda

Tags: keras, reinforcement-learning, anaconda3, conda-forge, keras-rl

I am starting to work on a reinforcement learning model, but I am blocked at the moment as I have not been able to download one of the essential python packages yet: keras-rl.

More specifically, I would like to import the following 3 utilities:

```
from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import EpsGreedyQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
```

I use Anaconda (Spyder) for my coding activities, and I usually install the various packages via the CMD.exe Prompt.

However, I cannot seem to find on https://anaconda.org/ any information on this particular package.

Could someone assist please?

Thank you!
Makram

Comment: It looks like you will have to `pip` install it. Doesn't seem to be available via conda. See https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl#installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install pip via conda using

```
conda install pip
```

then you can use pip to install like here

```
pip install keras-rl2
```

and everything will work just fine